# Which of two elements appeared in webdriver selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I click a button in selenium and then I have two possible scenarios: element with class="success" or element with class="error" appears.
How to get which element appeared?
I tried this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='success'], [class='error']"))
```

but it returns something like this, which doesn't give me much information about element that appeared:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="832d019b49d34662dfa548c823cc1d2e", element="e5a38fb7-88c1-4bd6-93b5-b48a1578d871")>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out what the found element is, you should call `element.get_attribute("class")` and you'll get the class information of the element.

Basically you could

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='success'], [class='error']")).get_attribute('class')
```